# Western Canada ShapeFiles (Meridian, Township, Section and Quarter)?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, city, canada

I want to create a TileGrid Map for Western Canada of the 36 "Townships" (where each "Township" has 16 sections). I want to create grid tiles from ShapeFiles/kml/kmz or any other format file.

I found the following link which points to a ShapeFile for the Alberta Altas Regions only.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143323/dls-grid-for-province-alberta-canada.

I would like to find more data of Western Canada's "Townships". Does anyone know of a reliable source for this vector data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best sources for Canadian Geospatial data is the Canadian government's [Open Data Portal](https://open.canada.ca/) and the [Canadian Census Boundary files](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm).

After doing a quick search through the Census data, it appears that 'Townships' might only be an administrative unit at the provincial level. As such, another option is to download the specific townships directly from Open Data Canada (https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset?q=township+numbers&organization=nrcan-rncan&res_format=SHP&sort=). You may want to write a to download all the results or a script that targets only the names/codes of the townships that you want. Quickly looking over it, the data seems to be what you're looking for.

**EDIT**: I may have found exactly what you are looking for. Here is a link to an NRCan FTP with the Dominion Land Survey (DLS) spatial/cadastral data for Canada. This includes all townships and is divided by province. https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/canada-lands-surveys/11092#CLdata

Comment: Thanks for reply with more useful DLS refrences.Yeah exactly i was found the earlier same CLData link https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/canada-lands-surveys/11092#CLdata